# Illegal Start of Expression... Yet I've made sure to have the correct operators

Tags: java, expression

getting an error here on the second else if.... I don't understand how it's happening whatsoever as the rest of them have no errors and are stated the same way! Would appreciate any input on this.

The error states;
error: illegal start of expression

Here is the code;

```
/**
 * @(#)Exercise4.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2014/10/20
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    float unit, cost; 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please Enter The Units Used: ");
    unit = input.nextFloat();

    if (unit <= 99)
        {
        cost = (unit*0.05);
        }
    else if (unit > 99 && unit <= 200)
        {
        cost = ((99*0.05) + (unit*(0.03)));
        }
    else if (unit > 200 && <= 300)
        {
        cost = (((99*0.05) + (200*0.03)) + (unit*0.02));
        }
    else if (unit>300)
        {
        cost = ((((99*0.05) + (200*0.03)) + (100*0.02)) + (unit*0.01));
        }   
    System.out.println("\nThe Cost Of Your Mobile Phone Bill Is: EUR" + String.format("%.2f",cost));

    }


}
```

Comment: too many parentheses ?

Comment: you try to compare int with float ?

Answer (score 3):

This

```
else if (unit > 200 && <= 300)
```

should be

```
else if (unit > 200 && unit <= 300)
```

You missed `unit` in the test. Also, you should make `cost` a `double` if you will multiply by a `double`.

```
float unit; 
double cost;
```

Comment: unit is float and the op tries to compare with int which is 200?

Comment: Perfecto, thank you very much! Now I just got to change float to double :)

Comment: @KickButtowski That's legal, the problem was leaving `unit` out of the test completely. `unit > 200` and *what* `<= 300`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Also, how do I format a double (since cost is double) to 2 decimal places? I know float is %.2f but I'm not sure about doubles....

Comment: @alannm37 The same (*no change required*) way.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you, appreciate the swift responses.

Answer (score 0):

A few changes are required here:

1. Correct 3rd if condition.
2. Change float type to double (Showing loss of precision error).
3. Initialize `cost = 0;`

and then it works...

Comment: it showed me err for not initializing var  cost so i initialized..